difference between a cox regression with a time varying covariate and discrete time cox model
I am curious about the difference between a discrete-time Cox model and Cox regression with a time-dependent covariate. My dataset includes a single event variable and a binary covariate, as shown below. Can I consider the treatment as a time-dependent covariate? I know the value of hazard ration=0.4 (from a similar study). I was wondering which of these methods is the right one to choose.
ID   TIME    EVENT   Treatment (covariate)
1     0        0         0
1     1        0         1
1     2        1         1
2     0        0         0
2     1        0         0
2     2        0         1


It's possible to have any combination of discrete/continuous-time models along with time-varying/fixed covariates. If you have a time-varying covariate, as you do, then you need to include that in the model. Your data seem to be set up for discrete-time modeling (one row per time interval per individual who's still at risk). If you only have a few discrete time points, as you seem to, that's the best choice. Using a binomial regression with a complementary log-log link (instead of the typical default logit link) makes this a "grouped proportional hazards" model that most compatible with how one thinks about proportional hazards. Make sure that your time-varying Treatment is indicated for all time intervals for which it's applicable.
Technically, Cox survival models are typically taken to be in continuous time (although they can handle tied event times). If you wanted to use a continuous-time Cox model you would have to switch to the "counting process" format explained in the R time-dependence vignette.

Thank you for the advice. I was wondering how I can modify the following code so that treatment can be considered a time-dependent covariate in a discrete time cox PH regression?  glm(event~ Treatment,family=binomial(link="cloglog"), data=df)

@elisa if there can be at most one event per individual, all you need to do is to incorporate Time as a covariate into the model in some way, along with Treatment and other important predictors. If there are just a few time points you can convert Time to a (multi-level) factor to include in the model. That makes no assumptions about baseline hazard and thus is closest in philosophy to Cox models. If there are a lot of levels you might consider a flexible model of Time, for example with a regression spline that lets the data tell you the shape of the association.

@elisa you might want to look at this answer and its links for more information. There is a textbook by Tutz and Schmid on discrete-time survival models, with a related R package, but it's much less approachable than the old publications by Singer and Willett.
